# How to implement 3 wpf buttons to share the same CanExecute result

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to implement 3 WPF buttons to share the same CanExecute() result without adding additional property in ViewModel.

Is there any implementation of this scenario in View directly ?

Buttons ::  A, B, C

If A command is running CanExecute for A,B,C is false
If B command is running CanExecute for A,B,C is false
If C command is running CanExecute for A,B,C is false
If none commands are running CanExecute is true

Comment: "in View directly". No, you implement this logic in the view model. Pass the same CanExecute predicate to all three commands.

Comment: I would advice against the approach(if possible), introducing a property makes the code more readable.

Comment: @user1316502: Did you follow my advice or what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You implement this logic in the view model. You could use the same `CanExecute` predicate for all three commands but the view model must still keep track of which commands that are currently executing and refresh the status of the commands by raising the `CanExecuteChanged` for each command.

Here is a sample implementation for you that disables all commands while any of them is executing:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Func<bool> canExecute = () => !_isAExecuting && !_isBExecuting && !_isCExecuting;
        CommandA = new RelayCommand(ExecuteA, canExecute);
        CommandB = new RelayCommand(ExecuteB, canExecute);
        CommandC = new RelayCommand(ExecuteC, canExecute);
    }

    public RelayCommand CommandA { get; }
    public RelayCommand CommandB { get; }
    public RelayCommand CommandC { get; }

    private bool _isAExecuting;
    private void ExecuteA()
    {
        _isAExecuting = true;
        RefreshCommands();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000))
            .ContinueWith(task => 
            {
                _isAExecuting = false;
                RefreshCommands();
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private bool _isBExecuting;
    private void ExecuteB()
    {
        _isBExecuting = true;
        RefreshCommands();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000))
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                _isBExecuting = false;
                RefreshCommands();
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private bool _isCExecuting;
    private void ExecuteC()
    {
        _isCExecuting = true;
        RefreshCommands();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000))
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                _isCExecuting = false;
                RefreshCommands();
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private void RefreshCommands()
    {
        CommandA.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        CommandB.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        CommandC.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="A" Command="{Binding CommandA}" />
        <Button Content="B" Command="{Binding CommandB}" />
        <Button Content="C" Command="{Binding CommandC}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```